# How to play 3gpp file?

Tags: recovery-mode

I was call recording , my battery died, the phone shut off while I was recording.
The file is on my phone. It is the correct size. It shows as an 3gpp extension. It's 2 MB so it's there. It will not play in window Media Player or with VLC player. It doesn't show up on the phone itself in the gallery, but it's there in file manager.

Comment: required more details in question (phone manufacturer, android version, root etc)

Answer (score 0):

Till where I know that Gallary doest shows the Music Files.
You can try to plah by using external file manager, like **ES File, ZArchiver**. etc

Answer (score 0):

You can try using inbuilt sound recorder which plays usually what it records, there should be option of call recordings in it. Also you easily search on Google play store about any 3gpp player.